# CSS styling mistake

Tags: html, css, django

I need to apply this theme for my django template using css. I wrote the css file but I have a mistake that not all the style is applied to the template. Please help.

This is the full code including the theme.css and the base html:

```css
nav {
  /* Repeating background image */
  background: url(http://weebtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/a.png);
  width: 210px;
  margin: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  /* Removes bullet points */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  /* Any child positioned absolutely will be positioned relative to this */
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  /* Fill all available horizontal space */
  display: block;
  /* Remove underline */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* 
 New CSS3 animations:
 apply transition to background property, taking 1s to change it 
 */
  transition: background 1s;
  -moz-transition: background 1s;
  -webkit-transition: background 1s;
  -o-transition: background 1s;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

nav a:hover {
  /* 
 RGBA background for transparancy: 
 last number(0.05) is the transparency 
 */
  background: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  color: #fff;
}

nav a:hover span {
  background: #7d2c41;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 210px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-top: 0;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: none;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #929292;
}

nav span {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

nav span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #3a3b3b;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 5px;
}

nav span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #3a3b3b;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  position: top;
}

.cust-dropdown {
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -120px;
  right: 20px;
}

.cust-dropdown ul {
  margin: -110;
  padding-left: -145;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href=""><span></span> Home </a></li>
      <li> <a href=""><span></span>AI assisted backtesting </a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href=""><span></span>Best stocks to trade today </a></li>
      <li> <a href=""><span></span>Get free data </a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="btn-group cust-dropdown pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
                </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Documentation</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make working fiddle.

Comment: which styles aren't applied, the ones from `theme.css` file?

Comment: yes this one isn't applied

Answer (score 0):

First you should have the prerequisites in your **settings.py** file:

1. you must have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. you must have defined a `STATIC_URL`:

   ```
   STATIC_URL = /static/
   ```

All this set, you put in your template file:

```
{% load static %}


<link href="{% static "css/theme.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) for more details.